# Vertically scrolling UICollectionView with self-sizing cells only displays half the cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, ios8, uicollectionviewcell

I've set up a `UICollectionView` (with the default flow layout, and vertical scrolling) with custom cells that load from a xib. The cells contain a couple of elements (a `UILabel` and a `UIView`) with constraints on them. I've set up the constraints such that the cell height grows as the label text height increases using the new `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` property that's available in iOS8, [`estimatedItemSize`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewFlowLayout_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewFlowLayout/estimatedItemSize):

```
layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(self.collectionView.frame.width, 100)
```

Everything works like a charm *except* there's one big problem: the `UICollectionView` loads only half the items as returned by the `numberOfItemsInSection` method. So, when the method returns, say, 10, my `UICollectionView` only displays 5 cells (but displays and lays them out perfectly).

Some relevant findings from my debugging attempts:

- I've been able to force the loading of the remaining items by calling `invalidateLayout` or changing the number of sections from 1 to 2. But those are just debugging hacks.
- Separately, everything works like a charm when I replace `estimatedItemSize` with the `itemSize` property, i.e. hard-coding the item size. But that defeats the self-sizing functionality I'd like to implement.

I'm assuming there's something wrong with how I'm thinking about self-sized cells. Specifically, I wonder if the problem has something to do with constraints.

I'd appreciate any help here.

Comment: Quick update: This seems to be an artifact of more pervasive bugs (or maybe we'll find out they're simply quirky implementation details) of self-sizing cells in UITableViews and UICollectionViews. I haven't gotten around to filing a radar against UICV self-sizing, but I put one in for UITableView — https://github.com/rainypixels/SelfSizingCells

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is due to a bug in iOS8 which still exists as of iOS8.3.

Flow layout collection views with self-sizing cells will fail to display some of their content if the `estimatedItemSize` is too small. This is despite the fact that according to the the API docs the only requirement on the `estimatedItemSize` is that it be non-zero to trigger the self-sizing behavior.

Only Apple is in a position to fix this. I think the best workaround in the mean time is to put an inflated value into estimatedItemSize`.

This repo demonstrates the issue: https://github.com/algal/SelfSizingCellsDemo. (I've filed a radar at rdar://18078598.)

Comment: Just ran into this while trying to support iOS8. Was mystified why my cells were disappearing on my iOS8 device and not on my iOS9 device. A very silly OS bug. Thank you!

Comment: (Do note, however, that setting the estimatedItemSize to something too big will make the scroll indicator jerk around while you're scrolling for the first time.)

Comment: I still have this on ios9

Comment: I still have this in iOS 10.2

Comment: still happens in iOS 11.

Comment: still happens in iOS 12 and counting

Answer (score 3):

The obvious non-hacky solution is to implement

```
flowLayout.collectionView(layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:)
```

but of course that is more code than you presumably have hoped for.

I would suggest you try two more things:

1. Try to experiment with more plausible estimated sizes. Also try the default value, `CGSizeZero`.
2. Check what happens in `preferredlLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes()` by examining the `layoutAttributes` parameter. Maybe you find a clue to why the other cells are "crowded out".

Comment: Thanks, Mundi. Yes you're right that `sizeForItemAtIndexPath` would defeat the purpose here. I gave both your suggestions a shot. Varying the 'CGSize' to have a width smaller than the collectionView width doesn't change things; the cells come in at a smaller width and lay themselves out as you'd expect in a flow layout. Everything looks in order in `layoutAttributes`, too. That said, there is some crowding out going on because the width of the `contentsize` property of the UICollectionView is greater than 320pt (I'm testing for iPhone right now).

Comment: Oh, I spent some time exploring the iOS dev forums, and while there's not much about self-sizing `UICollectionView` cells, the two related threads I could find report issues with the implementation of the feature. This could very well be a beta bug with the implementation.

Comment: What worked for me was setting the estimated size to CGSizeZero. I tried a "reasonable" estimate size as well as dynamically changing the estimated size and neither of the two helped.

Answer (score 1):

In a custom subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout

override prepareLayout like so:

```
- (void)prepareLayout {
  [super prepareLayout];
  CGSize contentSize = self.collectionView.contentSize;

  // Without this line, the scrolling doesn't go all the way to the bottom, right away but takes a while
  [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];
}
```

Comment: This seemed to help a little but doesn't totally resolve the issue. Even with this we still encounter the same bug. For example we found on certain collection views it helped on one device but then when we tested on another screen size the bug still happened.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem.
I was using `layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(373.0, 500.0)`  together with

```
preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes( layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes!
```

and I got exactly the  self-sizing behaviour i wanted, except I was only getting half the cells displayed.
The curious thing is when I changed the estimatedItemSize property to: `layout.estimatedItemSize = view.bounds.size` ALL the cells appear!!
Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: What is the `view` variable in your example? The UICollectionView?